# Append string to variable with loop, keeping the format intact in bash

Tags: bash, loops, dynamic, gitlab, variable-assignment

I am struck with the requirements for a sprint now and unable to crack it and request you to help me with a bit complex requirement.

1. I have a loop that outputs a list of JSON files.

`for i in my_list; do echo $i; done`
This list may vary between 15 and 30 based on the environment.

the `$i` output looks something like this "`apple.json`, `boy.json`", etc.

2. I now want the output of `$i` in the below curl command and keep on append to `--form "actions[][file_path]=JSON_FILES/$SYNC_ENV/$i.json" \` and  `--form "actions[][content]=<$i.json" \`.

Kindly note there are no files to append and all this is dynamic by assigning to a variable
eg: `my_ultimate_dynamic_command`

```
         ${CURLPOST} --form "branch=default-branch" \
                        --form "commit_message=[ Syncing ]" \
                        --form "actions[][action]=update" \
                        --form "actions[][file_path]=JSON_FILES/$SYNC_ENV/$i.json" \
                        --form "actions[][content]=<$i.json" \
                        -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$TOKEN" "https://gitlab.myorg.com/api/v4/projects/$prid/repository/commits"
```

3. expected output after the loop ends and echo of `$my_ultimate_dynamic_command` as below...

```
         ${CURLPOST} --form "branch=default-branch" \
                        --form "commit_message=[ Syncing ]" \
                        --form "actions[][action]=update" \
                        --form "actions[][file_path]=JSON_FILES/$SYNC_ENV/apple.json" \
                        --form "actions[][content]=<apple.json" \
                        --form "actions[][action]=update" \
                        --form "actions[][file_path]=JSON_FILES/$SYNC_ENV/boy.json" \
                        --form "actions[][content]=<boy.json" \
                         ...and so on until $i is empty
                        -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$TOKEN" "https://gitlab.myorg.com/api/v4/projects/$prid/repository/commits"
```

4. Finally, the dynamically generated variable should be executed as `eval $my_ultimate_dynamic_command`

Appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Storing commands in variables tends not to work except in very simple cases (see [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)), and `eval` just makes it even more confusing. Generally, the best solutions are 1) don't try to store it at all, just execute it directly, or 2) store it in an array rather than a plain variable (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
SYNC_ENV=????
TOKEN=????

declare -a CURLPOST
CURLPOST+=("some options")
CURLPOST+=("other options")
CURLPOST+=("--form" "\"branch=default-branch\"")
CURLPOST+=("--form" "\"commit_message=[ Syncing ]\"")


my_list="apple boy"
for i in ${my_list}; 
do 
    echo $i; 
    CURLPOST+=("--form" "\"actions[][action]=update\"")
    CURLPOST+=("--form" "\"actions[][file_path]=JSON_FILES/$SYNC_ENV/${i}\"")
    CURLPOST+=("--form" "\"actions[][content]=\<${i}\"")                         
done

CURLPOST+=("-H" "\"PRIVATE-TOKEN:$TOKEN\"" "\"https://gitlab.myorg.com/api/v4/projects/$prid/repository/commits\"")

# see the content of your array
declare -p CURLPOST

# exec curl with options 
curl "${CURLPOST[@]}"
```

Comment: Nice approach, but `\"actions[]...` looks strange. (Forgot to enclose with double quotes?)

Comment: I am testing the above solution and below is the issue

`declare -A CURLARGS`

`CURLARGS+=("--form" "\"branch\=sync\"")`
bash: CURLARGS: "--form": must use subscript when assigning associative array
bash: CURLARGS: "\"branch\=sync\"": must use subscript when assigning associative array

Comment: @VenuReddy use `declare -a `for indexed array instead of `declare -A ` for associative array